# Save bitmap canvas as png file in phone internal memory

Tags: android, memory, canvas, bitmap, internal

I am trying to save the bitmap canvas drawing to  png file to phone's internal memory as the phone I am using doesn't have external memory. But I am unable to see either in gallery or in file explorer. Help me in this.
Below is the code I am using.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/note.png");

Log.i(TAG,"PATH = " +file.getAbsolutePath());

try 
{

mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(file));

} 
catch (Exception e) 
{

e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: You are not closing the file output stream.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this code after you have added you photo :

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    String currentPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/MyAPP/APP" + n + ".jpg";
    File f = new File(currentPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

sometime what happens is that the image is added but the device cannot scan its position.

Comment: If i print the path value , it has /storage/emulated/0/myapp, i think the path is not correct. Hence file is not saved. My phone does'nt have external memory

Comment: I am able to save the image and its shown in folder SD card root directry. But if i open the image its blank with black color.

Comment: it might happen that you havnt given the proper type of image to be saved, and did u try the code given above?

Comment: Yes I tried. Only then I could see images in Gallery . if i check the details of the image saved, its size is 13MB. That means its not empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can set path for save your image using
  **android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()**
Definitely it will work.

```
// for path  to phone's internal memory 
    File cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "folder-name");
//for make the directory if not exist 
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
             cacheDir.mkdirs();
    f = new File(cacheDir, "myimage.jpg");
    URL url1 = new URL(your-url);
```